# Faster searching a huge array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

I am currently implementing an algorithm into matlab that searches through a database of customers which bought certain articles. This database looks as following:

```
[ 0   1   2   3   4   5 NaN NaN;
  4   6   7   8 NaN NaN NaN NaN;
...]
```

Just the size of that thing is size(data) = [90810 30]. Now I want to find frequent itemsets within that database (without making too much use of toolboxes). I will provide a toyexample here:

```
toyset = [
  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9;
  5,  6,  7,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;
  5,  6,  7,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;
  1,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN;
  2,  4,  8, 11, 12,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN];
```

This would generate the following itemsets when applying a minimum support of 0.5 [support = (occurences_of_set) / (all_sets) ]:

```
frequent_itemsets = [
  7,NaN,NaN;
  6,NaN,NaN;
  5,NaN,NaN;
  6,  7,NaN;
  5,  7,NaN;
  5,  6,NaN;
  5,  6,  7];
```

My problem now is finding how frequent the itemset is in the dataset. Currently I use the following algorithm (which works perfectly fine btw):

```
function list = preprocess(subjectArray, combinations, progressBar)
% =========================================================================
% 
% Creates a list which indicates how often an article-combination given by
% combinations is present in the array of Customers
% 
% =========================================================================
% 
%   preprocesses the array; Finds the frequency of articles
%   subjectArray    - Array that contains customer data
%   combinations    - The article combinations to be found
%   progressBar     - The progress bar to indicate the progress of the 
%                     algorithm 
% 
% =========================================================================

    [countCustomers,maxSizeCustomers] = size(subjectArray);
    [countCombinations,sizeCombinations] = size(combinations);
    list=zeros(1,countCombinations);

    for i = 1:countCustomers
        waitbar(i/countCustomers,progressBar,sprintf('Preprocess: %.0f/%.0f\nSet size:%.0f',i,countCustomers,sizeCombinations));
        for k = 1 : countCombinations
            helpArray = zeros(1,maxSizeCustomers);
            help2Array = zeros(1,sizeCombinations);
            for j = 1:sizeCombinations
                helpArray = helpArray + (subjectArray(i,:) == combinations(k,j));
                help2Array(j) = any(helpArray);
            end
            list(k) = list(k) + all(help2Array);
        end
    end
end
```

My only problem is that is takes AGES!!! Literally!! Is there any simple possibility (except for sets of length 1, I know that can be made faster by simple counting) to make this faster?

I think that this:

```
helpArray = helpArray + (subjectArray(i,j) == combinations(k,:));
```

is the bottleneck? But I am not sure since I don't know how fast matlab does certain operations.

Thanks for looking into it, mind_

What I ended up with doing:

```
function list = preprocess(subjectArray, combinations)
% =========================================================================
% 
% Creates a list which indicates how often an article-combination given by
% combinations is present in the array of Customers
% 
% =========================================================================
% 
%   preprocesses the array; Finds the frequency of articles
%   subjectArray    - Array that contains customer data
%   combinations    - The article combinations to be found
% 
% =========================================================================

    [countCustomers,maxSizeCustomers] = size(subjectArray);
    [countCombinations,sizeCombinations] = size(combinations);
    list=zeros(1,countCombinations);


    if sizeCombinations == 1
        for i = 1 : countCustomers
            for j = 1 : maxSizeCustomers
                x = subjectArray(i,j) + 1;
                if isnan(x), break; end
                list(x+1) = list(x+1) + 1;
            end
        end
    else
        for i = 1:countCombinations
            logical = zeros(size(subjectArray));
            for j = 1:sizeCombinations
                logical = logical + (subjectArray == combinations(i,j));
            end
            list(i) = sum(sum(logical,2) == sizeCombinations);
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks for all the support!

Comment: Can you explain conceptually how you get `frequent_itemsets`?

Comment: With the algorithm above I determine how frequent an itemset is in the data, then I delete all the infrequent itemsets. In the toyexample thus 0-4 and 8-12. then I build all possible combinations of the remaining and run the algorithm again. In the toyexample: 5,6 5,7 6,7

Comment: Oh yes: what I also do is to shrink the data afterwards so that I don't have to look over itemsets that do not contain any frequent itemsets over and over again.

Comment: Literally ages? did you test it for more than 300 years?

Comment: ... Really?! Please say something constructive or leave your comments on youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three suggestions I see right off the bat:

First, your waitbar is adding an additional three and half minutes to your search. According to this thread: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261380 it takes code going through 240,000 items an extra 550 seconds to execute if you include the waitbar, scale that to 90,000 and you still have 3 and a half minutes of extra time.

To calculate the initially frequent options, use the sum of logical indexing, for example, see how frequent a 7 occurs in your dataset.

```
logical7=subjectArray==7;
numOf7s=sum(sum(logical7));
```

Do this for each value, I have a feeling that even though there will be extra code, it will speed up the initial processing quite a bit.

To make that code nicer, you can do things like

preallocate logical mat, with each 3d slice representing a number (6th slice represents freq. = 5, 7th slice represents freq. = 6)

`logMat=zeros([size(subjectArray) maxPossibleVal+1])` %Max Possible val is 9 in toy box ex.

then fill each slice with the logical# matricies

```
for i=0:maxPossibleVal
  logMat(:,:,i+1) = subjectArray==i;
end
```

Once again, you can get your sums from each logical slice and those that are less than a certain threshold, you can remove from your log. mat (I would also use logical indexing to remove the slices that don't meet the threshold)

Now the nice thing about having everything logically indexed is you can combine your slices with addition or multiplication to get the different combination frequencies. You could even rotate the result of these operations and then use the "sum" command, followed by logical indexing to get the frequency that the two or three numbers occur together.

```
logM7=logMat(:,:,8)
logM8=logMat(:,:,9)
```

`combo7and8=logical(double(logM7)+double(logM8))`

%You could probably replace this maybe with an | to make this simpler/faster

```
freq7and8=sum(sum(combo7and8')==2)
```

%sum by default finds sum of columns, turn our rows into columns, then figure out what rows are equal to 2, add all the logical 1's together, and you have the freq. of the 7 and 8s in each dataset.

**This entire post can be summarized by two things:**

**Take off the waitbar**

**Know that it is possible to use logical indexing almost everywhere in your code, which is much faster than for loops**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I first will need to understand every bit that you just wrote but it looks very nice! Thanks for your time! I like to keep the waitbar for now, later when I include runtime analysis I will take it out of the algorithm. It is only there to comfort me that something is happening.

Comment: For the waitbar, there are quite a few workarounds, remember that the waitbar only has at most 300 increments, you don't need to update and render it 90,000 times for 300 updates. Use a mod operator or something like that. Alternatively, just display "Hey, I am working" at the start if you just want to know that it is indeed going. Something faster than waitbar is also doing just text, check out this link: <http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16213-another-text-waitbar/content/progress.m>. Lastly, really really look into logical indexing! :)

Comment: Yes, I will, thanks, it speeded up things quite a bit!! For the initial step I do something else actually: I simply loop once through the matrix and increment vector(matrix(i,j)+1) with every step ... that's even faster at least for the initial step (even if logical indexing looks nicer :D).

Comment: Awesome, good to hear! Sorry the logical indexing didn't give an immediate speed up, it may prove beneficial with the permutations, but all the code above was just ideas from the top of my head so I haven't been able to test any of it. ...If you wanted to accept my answer, that would be alright with me ;) haha keep us updated on what ends up working best in the long run!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but I cannot comment (my reputation is too low, I suppose)
Frequent itemset mining is quite complex. 
If you have a huge dataset and you choose a low threshold for an item(set) to be frequent, with your approach (apriori?) you have to be prepared to wait a long time :)
Usually when you deal with nested for loops with matlab you experience low performance, too.
What threshold did you choose? how large is your dataset?

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway ... as stated above the size of my dataset is [90810 30]. And you took the right guess it's apriori, indeed. I wanted to get the Matrixpart right before trying to implement trees in MATLAB. So that I have some sort of control. My Threshold now is 5%. My problem is one specific item that has a support of 51% ... That makes the computation rather slow since I can't get rid of more than 49% of the customers easily.

Comment: well, as I stated apriori is the most naive approach. If you get too many frequent items in the first phase (item counting) with such threshold I suggest you to increase it until the execution time becomes reasonable.
A solution to improve the speed of your code can be to try to put  your operations in "matrix operation" form: matlab performs the same matrix operations in matrix form extremely faster than it performs in for loops.

Comment: Okay, that would be worth a try ... thanks! Thus not iterating over all combinations but doing it in "one" calculation as a matrix and not as a vektor? Okay I'll try that!